# Covariant functor preserves chain homotopy

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C_\bullet$ and $C'_\bullet$ be two chain complexes of $A$-modules, $A$ a $K$-algebra, and $f_\bullet,g_\bullet: C_\bullet \to C'_\bullet$ two homotopic morphisms. Show that, for any covariant functor $F$ the morphisms $F(f_\bullet)$ and $F(g_\bullet)$ are homotopic.

This seems to be a nice problem, but I don't see how it can be proved in the case when the functor $F$ is not $K$-linear.

Comment: Are you sure the functor is not supposed to be additive (preserving finite products)? I am fairly sure there is a counterexample to the general case…

Comment: If $F$ is not additive, then $F(C_\bullet)$ might not even be a chain complex!

Comment: I agree with both of you, I'm going to add this hypothesis to the original problem.